# How to restore the Qt Creator Designer widget box?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

This sounds stupid, but I accidentally removed the widget box in Qt Creator's Design view, where you could select labels and buttons etc. I'm sure that's simple to get it back, but I've searched everywhere, and I can't seem to find it...

[image: screenshot of the missing widget box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu path is Window->Views->Widget box:

[image: menu path screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If you've really thrown off the editor layout, you can reset to the default layout.

Window->Views->Reset to Default Layout

Answer (score 2):

other answers seems outdate. I did following

View -> Workspace -> Manage

then selected Essentials and clicked reset button

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: This resets to how the windows were, Thankyou..  But im missing a ton of stuff like  labels, buttons, and the entire widget panel.. is it because im python?